# Establishing a many to many association with the .build method

Tags: activerecord, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-7

I've been banging my head against this for a few days, and I know of a hacky work around but I'm trying to adhere to the "Rails Way" as much as possible.

I have a Connector model, and a WiringHarness model that are associated through a join table WiringHarnessConnector.

relevant tables:

```
create_table "wiring_harnesses", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "company"
    t.integer "weekly_quota"
    t.integer "harnesses_completed"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_wiring_harnesses_on_user_id"
  end

create_table "connectors", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "part_number"
    t.string "company"
    t.integer "positions"
    t.uuid "terminal_id"
    t.uuid "prepop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["prepop_id"], name: "index_connectors_on_prepop_id"
    t.index ["terminal_id"], name: "index_connectors_on_terminal_id"
  end

create_table "wiring_harness_connectors", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.uuid "wiring_harness_id", null: false
    t.uuid "connector_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["connector_id"], name: "index_wiring_harness_connectors_on_connector_id"
    t.index ["wiring_harness_id"], name: "index_wiring_harness_connectors_on_wiring_harness_id"
  end
```

Here are the three models:

```
class WiringHarness < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :wiring_harness_prepped_wires
  has_many :prepped_wires, through: :wiring_harness_prepped_wires
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :prepped_wires

  has_many :wiring_harness_connectors
  has_many :connectors, through: :wiring_harness_connectors
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :connectors

  self.implicit_order_column = "created_at"

  enum :components, [:prepped_wire, :connector]
end


class Connector < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :terminal
  has_many :wiring_harness_connectors
  has_many :wiring_harnesses, through: :wiring_harness_connectors
  # belongs_to :prepop

  self.implicit_order_column = "created_at"
end

class WiringHarnessConnector < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :wiring_harness
  belongs_to :connector

  self.implicit_order_column = "created_at"
end
```

Here are the new and create methods in the wiring harness controller

```
def new
    @wiring_harness = WiringHarness.find(params[:wiring_harness_id])
    @connector = @wiring_harness.connectors.build
end

 def create
    @wiring_harness = WiringHarness.find(params[:connector][:wiring_harness_id])
    @connector = @wiring_harness.connectors.build(connector_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @connector.save
        format.html { redirect_to connector_url(@connector), notice: "Connector was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @connector }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @connector.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

connector _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@connector) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :part_number %>
    <%= f.input :company %>
    <%= f.input :positions %>

    <%# Not sure if I need this but it was one of the routes I was playing around with. %>
    <%= f.input :wiring_harness_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: @wiring_harness.id } %>

  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And then the route:

```
resources :wiring_harnesses do
    resources :connectors
end
```

URL: http://localhost:3000/wiring_harnesses/98608696-8319-4784-b76b-a060e5f861da/connectors/new

Problem:

When trying to create a connector that will have a relationship with the wiring_harness an instance of the join table isn't being created. I thought that since my relationships are established in the models and that I'm using a build method based off the wiring harness that an instance of the WiringHarnessConnector table would be built and that a relationship going both ways would be established i.e @connector.wiring_harnesses & @wiring_harnesses.connectors would both work automatically.

When I bind the create method after both the instance methods (@wiring_harness & @connector) I can call @wiring_harness.connectors and the new connector is returned inside of an array. But if I call connector.wiring_harnesses, an empty array is returned.

This doesn't make sense to me because if the join table isn't being created. I would think, that neither relationships would work.